# Tensorboard graph recall

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am training an object detector and I ran the evaluation job. I see certain graphs in the tensorboard. What is DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10 vs AR@100 vs AR@100(medium) in the tensorflowboard as shown. And what is the difference between DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP, mAP(large), mAP(medium), mAP(small), mAP(0.50IOU) and mAP(0.75IOU)? Please help I am very new to this thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

'DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP': mean average precision over classes averaged over IOU thresholds ranging from .5 to .95 with .05 increments.

'DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU': mean average precision at 50% IOU

'DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU': mean average precision at 75% IOU

'DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small)': mean average precision for small objects (area < 32^2 pixels).

'DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (medium)': mean average precision for medium sized objects (32^2 pixels < area < 96^2 pixels).

'DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (large)': mean average precision for large objects (96^2 pixels < area < 10000^2 pixels).

'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1': average recall with 1 detection.

'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10': average recall with 10 detections.

'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100': average recall with 100 detections.

'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small)': average recall for small objects with 100.

'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (medium)': average recall for medium objects with 100.

'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (large)': average recall for large objects with 100 detections.

Comment: What does the average recall with 1 / 10 / 100 detections mean?

Comment: this link helps answer that: http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval ...  I think "@10" means it's taking the 10 highest confidence predictions, across classes, for a single image and calculating metrics on just those 10 detections.  Obviously recall will be hurt if there are 20 objects in the image, since max recall is now 0.5.

Comment: @Scorpio, what if i don't have small objects (`area < 32^2 pixels`) in my dataset? will it return `Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100 ] = -1.000`

Comment: @Sanjay Earlier versions use to give -1 output for that. I haven't checked the latest code base

Answer (score 7):

As @kmh pointed out, a brief (but not great) explanation can be found [here](http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval).
The actual mathematical definition can be found in the code [here](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocotools/cocoeval.py).

mAP = Mean Average Precision
mAR = Mean Average Recall

When they say mean average, unless specified otherwise, they mean that they are computing these metrics across all examples (i.e. images), classes, and IOU thresholds (which are in range .50:.05:.95, i.e. [0.5, 0.55, ..., 0.90, 0.95]).

So, about these 12 metrics:

**Precision (mAP)**

- **DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP**: as explained above, it means that you compute the precision over all images, classes, and IOU thresholds and then take the average.
- **DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.50IOU**: here, it specifies the IOU, so in this case it doesn't go over all IOU thresholds, only the specified one. This metric is the average precision using only IOU=0.5 (but still going over all images and classes). The idea of this metric is to give you a rough sense of precision if you are not super strict about the position of your bounding boxes (you only require at least IOU=0.5 to count as positive).
- **DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP@.75IOU**: Same as above, but using IOU=0.75 instead of IOU=0.5. The idea of this metric is to give you a rough sense of precision if you are somewhat strict about the position of your bounding boxes (you require at least IOU=0.75 to count as positive).
- **DetectionBoxes_Precision/mAP (small, medium, large)** these are essentially the same as mAP above, but sliced by the size of the bounding boxes. The small one is only computing mAP for bounding boxes that are small (area < 32*32 pixels). Medium is for bounding boxes with 32*32 < area < 96*96. Large is for area > 96*96 (in reality the implementation for large is 96*96 < area < 1e5*1e5). These metrics allow you to get a sense if your model is performing better/worse in specific sizes of bounding boxes.

**Recall (mAR)**

- **DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@(1, 10, 100)**: These are mean average recalls sliced by the the number of detections in the image. AR@1 means that it will compute the mean average recall across all images with at most 1 detection (i.e. 0 or 1), across all classes, and across all IOU thresholds. For AR@10, it would do the same, but across all images with at most 10 detections (i.e. 0 <= n <= 10). AR@100 is for at most 100 detections.
- **DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100 (small, medium, large)**: These are mean average recalls sliced by the size of the detected bounding box. Notice the AR@100 in the metric. This means that it only takes images with at most 100 detections (in general, this means most or all images). Sizes are the same as in mAP above (i.e. small: [0, 32*32], medium: [32*32, 96*96], large: [96*96, 1e5*1e5])