# Interpreting output of `model_main.py` in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I was able to successfully train my model by running `model_main.py` and got this result:

> Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100 ] = 0.344
>
> Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ]
>   = 0.514
>
> Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.75      | area=   all | maxDets=100 ]
>   = 0.376
>
> Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.112
>
> Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.317
>
> Average Precision  (AP) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.504
>
> Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=  1
>   ] = 0.303
>
> Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets= 10
>   ] = 0.474
>
> Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=   all | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.509
>
> Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= small | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.222
>
> Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area=medium | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.507
>
> Average Recall     (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= large | maxDets=100
>   ] = 0.676

How do we interpret this? What does `area` represent? Where is the mAP value?

Comment: I would like to know the same. Going by these small numbers how was your result quality? What are the state of the art numbers supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer (area, mAP) can be found in this post here:

[Tensorboard graph recall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068835/tensorboard-graph-recall/52097660)

Your "Average Recall (AR) @[ IoU=0.50:0.95 | area= all | maxDets= 1 ]" corresponds to "DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1" in the answer there.